# Debian Firmware bug TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata

Tags: debian, intel, firmware

On Debian, when machine is boots,
it shows error:

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; 
please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)
```

I did

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it didn't help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you should check if there is an update available for your BIOS/UEFI. If you are lucky your motherboard manufacturer provides an update.
BIOS updates sometimes include processor firmware updates.
(That is the best case, as it would be persistent after an OS reinstall.)

Then, depending on your processor brand, the following command line :

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode
```

will automatically apply the latest processor firmware when the linux kernel is booting. This is a non persistent solution, but here you rely on Intel/AMD/Debian/Ubuntu, not anymore on your motherboard manufacturer.

To know the firmware version applied by your Linux kernel (maybe), use that command :

```
dmesg | grep microcode
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that need install intel-microcode packages, Just do

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```